# How do I prevent the raw WSGI python file from being read?

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, wsgi

I am using mod_wsgi with apache to serve the python application. I have a directive in the VirtualHost entry as follows `WSGIScriptAlias /app /home/ubuntu/www/app.wsgi`. I also have `DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/www/`. Therefore, if the user attempts to read /app.wsgi it gets the raw file. If I try to block access to it via .htaccess, the application becomes unusable. How do I fix this? Is there a way to do so without moving the file out of the DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 0):

This is far from the best option, but it does seem to work: I added `WSGIScriptAlias /app.wsgi /home/ubuntu/www/app.wsgi` to the VirtualHost as well so that it will run the app on that uri instead of returning the raw file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not stick the WSGI file in the DocumentRoot directory in the first place. You have created the situation yourself. It doesn't need to be in that directory for WSGIScriptAlias to work.